# How to make a navigation menu full width and with a transition

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a dropdown navigation.  I would like the dropdown part to be full-width when you hover and to have the dropdown menu fade in when you hover.  An example of this is on the LA Phil site - https://www.laphil.com/

I've tried adding a second div to just the dropdown menu content, but that breaks it.

```
@media (min-width: 769px){
.primary-navigation ul.navigation-item-group li.nav-item.has-submenu ul.submenu.sub-menu {
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    padding-top: 2em;
}
.primary-navigation {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: initial;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4em;
}
.primary-navigation ul li:hover > ul { 
  display: flex;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.primary-navigation ul ul > li { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
}
.primary-navigation ul ul {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ee9fb5;
    border-top: 2px solid #ee9fb5;
}
.submenu.sub-menu {
    padding: 1em;
}
}

.primary-navigation ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.primary-navigation > li > ul.sub_menu {
  min-width: 10em;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.primary-navigation ul li { padding: 0px; }

.primary-navigation > ul > li { display: inline-block; }

.primary-navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.primary-navigation ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  min-width: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }

.menu ul ul > li { position: relative; }

.primary-navigation ul ul > li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.primary-navigation ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

 @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
a.menu-link {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
 // padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


.primary-navigation {
  clear: both;
  min-width: inherit;
  float: none;
}

.primary-navigation,
.primary-navigation > ul ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.primary-navigation > li > ul.sub-menu {
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}


.primary-navigation.active,
.primary-navigation > ul ul.active { max-height: 100em; }

.primary-navigation ul { display: inline; }

.primary-navigation li,
.primary-navigation > ul > li { display: block; }

.primary-navigation > ul > li:last-of-type a { border: none; }

.primary-navigation li a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.primary-navigation li.has-submenu > a:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -1em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.55em 0em;
}

.primary-navigation li.has-submenu > a.active:after { content: "-"; }

.primary-navigation ul ul,
.primary-navigation ul ul ul {
  display: inherit;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  border: none;
}
a.menu-link:after {
  content: "\2630";
  font-weight: normal;
}

a.menu-link.active:after { content: "\2715"; }

li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ee9fb5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
}
.primary-navigation .nav-item a, .primary-navigation .flexMenu-viewMore a {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: .5em;
}
.primary-navigation ul ul > li a {
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
.submenu li {
    font-size: xx-small;
}
.navigation-item-group {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
 }

<nav class="primary-navigation" role="navigation" id="menu">
    <ul class="navigation-item-group">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" title="Calendar">Calendar</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Category" title="Link">Category1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Link" title="Link">Category2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li ><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Link" title="Link">Category3</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li ><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Link" title="Link">Category4</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li ><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#Link" title="Link">Category5</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li ><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://pittsburghsymphonyorchestra.bigcartel.com/" title="Link">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I would like it to look like the LA Phil dropdown menu -

https://www.laphil.com/

When the user hovers over the menu, I'd like the dropdown menu bar to stretch from each side of the screen.  Also, when the user hovers, I'd like the dropdown content to transition in.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `.primary-navigation ul ul` and `.primary-navigation ul li:hover>ul`, you can modify their properties using visibility, opacity and transition to create the effect instead of being based on display.

For streching the whole screen width, you can apply `width: 100vw` for `.primary-navigation ul ul`.

```css
.primary-navigation ul ul {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.32s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.primary-navigation ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.32s 0.12s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Azametzin!  With this, the transition works great!  When I hard code a width that works for my browser, it doesn't work with a browser size that is less than or greater than mine.  For example, when I set the width to 100vw, it's beyond the width of my screen and the menu is not visible on the left.  Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: No problem. It should not happen like that, but I have some suspicions of what it might be. Could you provide a JSFiddle or Codepen with the code to show better what you mean?

Comment: I think I know what you mean. When you use percentage, like `width: 100%`, it is related to the next parent with `position: relative`. So it would be good if you adjust the parent width in accordance. But if you use `width: 100vw`, it will be 100% of the browser size, so if it is no positioned in the right-end, it will overflow to the left.